# Function that equals its own Mellin transform

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functions, mellin-transform

I know that the Gaussian distribution is its own Fourier transform.
There was a similar post about what function is its own Laplace transform that was answered.
I was wondering if there exist a function such that
$$
f(s) = \int_0^\infty f(x) x^{s-1}dx
$$
I don't have any use for finding such a function but I am just curious about it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).